# Как вырезать сборщик данных VScode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Всем привет! Я планирую перейти на VScode, но читая условия соглашения заметил, что программа собирает данные, и я хотел бы вырезать сборщик данных. Подскажите, как это сделать?
Есть еще один вопросик: если скачать торрент версию, то сборщик данных по-прежнему будет работать?

Comment: собираетесь взламывать пентагон? Что у вас может быть такого интересного для Майкрасофта?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Заходите в настройки <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> и ищите в настройках "telemetry" и снимаете две галочки. Это немного уменьшит прыть, хотя говорят, что даже после этого шлет. Если хочется больше свободы, можно посмотреть на [VS Codium](https://vscodium.com/), который решает эти проблемы.

Comment: Большое спасибо, бро!)

Comment: Как я понимаю, VScodium это некий репак VScode от сообщества?

Comment: как то так. (тут принято тыкать стрелку вверх и галочку, если ответ нравится)

Comment: намек понял, еще раз спс)

Comment: возникла еще одна проблемка... Как установить какой либо плагин на VScodium?

Comment: вот в этом и вся загвоздка. Но это решаемо https://github.com/VSCodium/vscodium/blob/master/DOCS.md#extensions-marketplace

Comment: Эх, вот бы всегда все так просто решалось. Спс